# Conectar MVC Identity a otra base de datos utilizando el modelo de capas

Tags: mvc, webservice, entity-framework, wcf, identity

Buen Día, llevo varios días intentando realizar un aplicativo con el modelo de Autenticación de usuarios que integra MVC y me doy cuenta que para realizar las autenticaciones de usuario no utiliza Entity Framework(EF), sino mas bien un modelo diferente Identity que integra el mismo EF, en proyectos anteriores se me hacia muy fácil utilizar EF, programando por capas e incluso realizando una conexión por WCF Web Service (Ws) para el registro de productos y funciona muy bien. Pero cuando quiero hacer lo mismo que hacia con EF pero ahora utilizando Identity no me funciona, no me permite conectarme a una DB que ya he creado con los campos y las configuraciones correspondientes, logro separar los modelos por capas pero no accede a mi base de datos y ni hablar cuando intento utilizarlo con WCF la verdad creo que no se como se hace pensé que era lo mismo que utilizar Ef.

Agradecería cualquier información ya que soy nuevo en este tema y he buscado mucho en diferentes sitios web pero todos utilizan la base de datos que brinda por defecto el proyecto web o conectan directamente la base de datos al proyecto web.

Answer (score 0):

pues no son dos maneras de autenticacion.

Identity- es usado para la Autenticacion y autorizacion de algun metodo o servicio. Es una libreria que te ahorra bastante codigo.

EF es para la parte de datos, Identity puede hacer uso de EF para acceder a los datos de usuario y validacion de permisos.

Mas o menos es un pequeno resumen espro esto aclare un poco tu confusion.

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad si aclara parte de mi confusión, me queda todavía la duda de como utilizar EF para realizar procesos de autenticacion o si decido utilizar EF para ese servicio me toda realizar toda la programación que me ahorra Identity?

Comment: Recuerda EF es para la implementacion de la capa de datos no realiza la autentication, puedes utilizar EF para acceder a la informacion de Usuarios y sus permisos .  De echo supongamos que con EF accedes a tabla de usuarios y obtienes nombre usuario, password y role. Una vez que lo obtienes realizas una simple clase para validacion de permisos, sin necesidad de usar Identity.